# Accessing delegate callback of AVPictureInPictureController for a WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, wkwebview, picture-in-picture

I need to be able to access the delegate callback method, `pictureInPictureControllerDidStopPictureInPicture(_:)` of the native `AVPictureInPictureController` of a `WKWebView`. `AVPictureInPictureController` doesn't have the global notification events like the old `MPMoviePlayerViewController` does and I can't create my own instance of `AVPictureInPictureController` to use with the web view to access the delegate callbacks. I can find no documentation on how to hook into this inner `AVPictureInPictureController` of the `WKWebView` object. I was hoping there was some way to do it with KVO at least.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForPictureInPicture.html

> The WebKit framework provides the WKWebView class, which supports Picture in Picture in iOS 9.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avpictureinpicturecontrollerdelegate/1614717-pictureinpicturecontrollerdidsto

Answer (score 2):

if you have any access to your `AVPictureInPictureController` you can simply set it's delegate and implement the callback

```
class MyWebView: WKWebView {

    self.myPictureInPictureController.delegate = self

}

extension MyWebView: AVPictureInPictureControllerDelegate {
    func pictureInPictureControllerDidStopPictureInPicture(_ pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController) {
        //code
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not creating a standalone `AVPictureInPictureController`. I'm relying on the one that is internal to `WKWebView`.

Comment: I tried to subclass as you suggested but it still doesn't give me access to the internal AVPictureInPictureController. I need to take advantage of the WKWebView version because I'm loading preroll ads and video using a custom Javascript video player. Creating my own AVPlayer in a AVPictureInPictureController won't give me this ability.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find that there is a notification called `PGPictureInPictureProxyPictureInPictureActiveChangedNotification` which is called when the video moves to picture-in-picture and then again when the picture-in-picture is closed. I'm sure it could get changed or removed at any point but it seems to be working for now.